# Save a Derivative

Tags: variable-definitions, save

I have defined the derivative of a function

`Derivative[1][f][x_] := Sin[x]`

How can I save this definition in a file?  Derivatives are not included in `FullDefinition[f]`, so `Save["file.m",f]` won't work.  The best I can do now is

`WriteLine["file.m","Derivative[1][f][x_] := Sin[x]"]`

Any ideas how to do this more properly?

Comment: This is weird, because if I say `g[x_]:=Log[x]+2` for example, I can get the `DownValues[g]` and it gives `{HoldPattern[g[x_]] :> Log[x] + 2}`. But if I define `Derivative[1][f][x_] := Sin[x]` - what happens then?? because `DownValues[f']` is empty. I guess this boils down to finding how to get `DownValues` for indexed functions and non-head forms.

Comment: Try the following `g[3][x_] := Tan[x]` and do `FullDefinition[g]`. That should work. Therefore I think in your case it's associating the definition with `Derivative` and not `f`. If you do `FullDefinition[Derivative]` you should see `f'[x_] := Sin[x]` appearing at the end. This means you have to save the definition of `Derivative`. You'll need to `Unprotect` the `Derivative` when you reload it, so it gets overwritten with your new definitions.

Comment: @flinty I don't think `Derivative` is protected. You can just do `Save[..., {f, Derivative}]` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
ClearAttributes[Derivative, {ReadProtected}]
Derivative[1][f][x_] := Sin[x]
Save["file.m", {f, Derivative}]
```

## Edit

Included the line that clears the ReadProtected attribute, in case it's necessary. It seems like this might depend on version or something, because for me `Derivative` never has that attribute in a new kernel.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  The output file just contains the attributes of `Derivative`.  I am using Kernel 11.2

Comment: On further investigation, you solution works if the `ReadProtected` is removed:
```ClearAttributes[Derivative, {ReadProtected}]```
It also adds the associated documentation string, but I can live with that.

Comment: Oh, that's strange. I did that once, but not in this kernel session. Looks like if you use `ClearAttributes[Derivative, {ReadProtected}]`, the attributes remain that way even between sessions.

Answer (score -1):

I did not fully understand the intention, it looks like you are trying to assign a function to an operator. If you use the name `df` the following works:

```
df[x_] := Sin[x]
(* save *)
Export["/tmp/test.wdx", df[x]]
(* clear *)
Clear@df
(* load *)
df[x_] := Evaluate@Import["/tmp/test.wdx"]
```

Comment: Your answer would be correct for saving the definition of the function itself.  I am asking how to save a definition of a derivative of the function.